# Developing a Chatroom in Flex ActionScript3 + Red5 , Remote Shared Object based UserList or Serverside?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, red5, shared-objects, flash-media-server

We are going to develop a simple chatroom in flex using Red5.

Should we store UserList in a Remote Shared Object or Server Side List?
Are there any example exit on Red5 or FMS , which uses Server Side programming and Remote Shared Objects? Red5 examples are not documented at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of our team members has created video tutorials for Shared Objects, the links are in the Red5 forum.
http://www.red5.org/forums/topic/21-sharedobject-tutorial/

Comment: there is not much documentation on serverside scripting for Red5 :( that's sad! Red5 might be powerfull and free, but it's hard to learn with no documentation. I understand that FMS is worth the money they ask for. It's easy to learn and actionscript based...

Comment: There's a lot of documentation, youtube tutorials, etc; A simple google search is all you need to get started. Other good locations: http://wiki.red5.org/  http://www.red5.org/forums/ or even here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If there will 10 or less users, you could use the FMS developer editions.  Check out [this](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/building-red5-applications-by-chris-allen/) for a good example of red5.

Comment: Scability is important and we want to based on opensource so we will use Red5 only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help u a bit. I learned here to handle the ShardedObjectbecause the RED5 Tutorials Links moved to Google Code sites and the Links arent anymore available. So heres the link:

http://www.zehnet.de/2008/04/11/red5-remote-sharedobject-experience-tips/